# Geometric proof for properties of Farey sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, triangles, farey-sequences

Let $P=(a,c)$ and $P^{'}=(b,d)$ be integral co-ordinates such that $\frac{c}{a}$ and $\frac{d}{b}$ are consecutive terms of [Farey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) sequence. If $O$ is the origin how do I prove no integral co-ordinate can lie  inside the triangle $OPP^{'}$ ?

Comment: What do you know about Farey sequences?  For example, do you know that each term is in simplest form?

Comment: yes I know the basic properties. I know that no integral point will lie on the segments $OP$ and $OP^{'}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *lattice point* is a point with integer coordinates.  You already know that $\frac{c}{a}$ and $\frac{d}{b}$ are in simplest form.  Thus, no lattice points lie on the segments $\overline{OP}$ or $\overline{OP'}$.  Assume that we have proven that no lattice points lie on the segment $\overline{PP'}$.  (I assume you have already done this based on your recent edit to your question.)

By [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem), the area of a triangle with lattice point vertices is $A=i+\frac{b}{2}-1$, where $i$ is the number of interior lattice points and $b$ is the number of lattice points on the boundary.  From the previous paragraph, we know that $b=3$.  If we can show that the area of $\triangle OPP'$ is $\frac12$, then we have shown that $i=0$, which is what we want to prove.

The area of $\triangle OPP'$ is $\frac12(ad-bc)$.  (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Using_coordinates).)  But since $\frac{c}{a}$ and $\frac{d}{b}$ are [Farey neighbors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence#Farey_neighbours), we have $ad-bc=1$.